# Lock release after calling interrupt

Tags: java, multithreading

I am having below Threads where I am trying to replicate the `interrupt` functionality

**Thread T1**

```
public void run() {
                synchronized (i) {

                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                    try {
                        i.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Inside r1");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
```

**Thread T2**

```
public void run() {
            synchronized (i) {
                System.out.println("Inside r2");

            }

        }
```

When I run the above 2 threads, I get the below output

```
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
    at InterruptTest$1.run(InterruptTest.java:17)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Inside r1
Inside r2
```

My Question is, after **wait()** in T1, the lock is released. Then how is the statement "Inside r1" executed without having the lock by T1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the point that

```
System.out.println("Inside r1");
```

is executed, the thread has the lock.

The documentation for the [Object#wait method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) says:

> The thread T is then removed from the wait set for this object and re-enabled for thread scheduling. It competes in the usual manner with other threads for the right to synchronize on the object; once it has regained control of the object, all its synchronization claims on the object are restored to the status quo ante - that is, to the situation as of the time that the wait method was invoked. Thread T then returns from the invocation of the wait method. Thus, on return from the wait method, the synchronization state of the object and of thread T is exactly as it was when the wait method was invoked.

When the thread enters the wait method, it gives up its claim on the lock (i's monitor).

While dormant the thread is still in the wait method.

In order for the thread to exit the method it must have re-acquired the lock on i.

So if a thread is leaving the wait method (whether due to being notified or interrupted or being spuriously-woken), it must get the lock back just to get out of the wait method.

Not having a condition variable to test in a while loop around the wait call, and the suspicious choice of i (for integer? are you mutating this??) for the name of the variable, make me think there are other problems.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand how it works. Let's go through it, step by step:

```
Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

This sets the interrupt flag on your own thread to 'true'. That's all interrupting a thread actually does, it does not mean the JVM is going to do anything particular about it. Just sets a boolean. That is all. Any further effects are because some code checks that flag.

```
i.wait();
```

Ordinarily, this will both [1] release the 'monitor' on whatever object `i` is pointing at (as if the `synchronized (i) {}` block hit the closing brace: Any other threads trying to synchronize on this object will now get to go), and also [2] wait around until somebody calls `notify()` or `notifyAll()` on the object `i` points at, at which point it will first re-acquire the monitor (like writing `synchronized (i) {`), which will never immediately work out as whatever just sent the notify still has the monitor (you can't notify if you don't hold the monitor).

But now.. it's trickier. Every JVM method that is specced as throwing `InterruptedException` interacts with that flag we set before: It will clear that flag and terminate the wait (by throwing that exception) if the flag is raised during its wait. If the flag is on BEFORE you even call the method, it will immediately terminate. So, does it release the monitor, and then try to immediately re-acquire it? I think whether it does or not is up to the VM implementation, so you must write your code such that it works, either way.

The crucial point is this: **regardless of how the wait() method ends (either by returning or by throwing the exception), the monitor on `i` is re-acquired before code execution continues)**.

Aside from `Unsafe` and other hackery it is **not possible** to be in a `synchronized` block without holding that monitor, the sole exception being that your thread doesn't hold the monitor for as long as it is waiting for a `wait()` call to finish one way or another.

```
System.out.println("Inside r1");
```

Therefore, the monitor has been re-acquired here.

```
Thread.sleep(1000);
```

This will wait 1000 milliseconds; after all, the previous wait() call has cleared the interrupt flag.

Then in the other thread:

```
synchronized (i) {System.out.println("Inside r2");}
```

This may run either [1] before the first thread even starts, [2] possibly, depending on the behaviour of `wait()` when the interrupt flag is set, right as thread 1 invokes `wait`. If it does this, then thread 1 will not continue until thread 2 is done, as it must acquire the monitor on i first before it can continue, or [3] after thread 1 is done.

There is no way for this code to execute the 2 println statements simultaneously. Even if `System.out.println` does not buffer, there is no way to get this code to print something like `"IInsinsiddee rr12"`. Without the `synchronized` stuff that'd be theoretically possible (but not really, as sysout is somewhat buffered on just about every platform I know of).

Comment: then why do we need the notify() method if the lock is going to be released only after the sync block is completed? What if I omit the notify() altogether?

Comment: Re, "...That's all interrupting a thread actually does." IMO that's a bit misleading. You admit later that setting the flag causes a blocked thread to throw `InterruptedException`. It's a bit like saying, "All _I_ did was pull the trigger," and then later admitting that, "Well, yeah, the trigger _did_ cause the gun to discharge..." It would be more words, but IMO easier for beginners to follow, if you would say up front that interrupting a thread sets the flag _and_ it causes the currently-blocked call (if any) to throw..."

Comment: @ghostrider One thread needs to wait on another to, say, finish parsing some database output. One way to do that is with wait/notify. The db-reader thread gets responses from the db, notifies the other thread (which doesn't wake up quite yet), finishes processing, and releases lock. Then the other thread can go. The alternative is.. Thread.sleep for 1000 msec and checking, which means you can be up to 1000 msec later than you needed to. Without the notify, the 'wait' would always wait the max time, with it, it waits until the lock is free.

Comment: @SolomonSlow that's misleading too: A blocked thread doesn't HAVE to throw InterruptedException. It's not written in stone. Some methods act like that, many don't (for example, if you're blocking on file access, network access, etc – you definitely don't get an InterruptedException and no guarantees that the thing the thread is frozen in will in fact be interrupted). So, 'causes the currently-blocked call to throw' is more misleading; only some blocking calls act like this.